# Change line appearance with some specific value in series

Tags: reactjs, echarts

I am using Echarts to display a simple line charts with 2 series.

The values of the two series can be numbers from 0 to 1.
One of the series can occasionally have null as value and makes the line interrupt.

I would prefer to change the appearance of the line to be dashed in case of null value, there is a proper way to accomplish that ?

```
 series: [
      {
        name: 'Line 1',
        type: 'line',
        lineStyle: {
          width: 2,
        },
        data: dataset.map(({ data }) => data),
        symbol: 'none',
      },
      {
        name: 'Line2',
        type: 'line',
        lineStyle: {
          width: 2,
        },
        data: dataset.map(({ data }) => data),
        symbol: 'none',
      },
    ],
```

[image: Actual Chart with line break]

A possible solution that came to my mined is to add a third series with a dashed line filtering the original series, but I am wondering if there is a proper way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think that there is some nice inbuild way for your usecase. You could use a [markLine](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#series-line.markLine) for the `null` intervals. [Here](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=line-simple&code=PYBwLglsB2AEC8sDeAoWsAeBBDEDOAXMmurGAJ4gCmRA5AMYCGYVA5sAE7m0A0J6AE2aMiAbVoBZGL1i0AKgFcqM2gHUqAlXIAWClQDEOEFQGVmphdFoBdEgF8-6cjnxFUpMpRqyAbowA2SrT2jrB4VEZUhLCi_MQe6BTUdP4Q0MqhHkJgIjEAjDwALDwA7EU8ABw8AJw8AEzWmbAOce4JSd60qem8cYLCYgCsPADMPNAK_v48AGyl45PTeY19sAC2jBwA1gAyad5tCWHkawBGwP500DAZq-jdVCYU_gd3pKCM9BAURAAMAHTDN7oADuEAEYG0RDqbxaR36OTEwJiyPQh3hHnowE4AjEBRGKwxHjhRLRqNIWJxYjGM0JpOayLpGNi9PirNglI4uJixRKTKJJNJ6NJnO5ojmyyaGLsjLetiOMuJJFsdgA3EA) is an example:

```js
option = {
  xAxis: {
    type: 'category',
    data: ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun']
  },
  yAxis: {
    type: 'value'
  },
  series: [
    {
      type: 'line',
      data: [1,4,7,4,8,9,2],
    },
    {
      type: 'line',
      data: [5,3,null,6,7,null,1],
      markLine: {
        symbol: 'none',
        lineStyle: {
          opacity: 0.5,
          width: 2
        },
        data: [
          [
            {
              coord: [1,3],
            },
            {
              coord: [3,6],
            }
          ],
          [
            {
              coord: [4,7],
            },
            {
              coord: [6,1],
            }
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
};
```

---

What I can also imagen working is putting your data into a [dataset](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#dataset), filling the `null` values with some interpolation, adding a dimension which keeps track of the `null` values and use this dimension for a [visaul map](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#visualMap-piecewise).